# How to multiply list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

If I have a list:

`val a: mutableListOf<Int> = (1,2,3,4)`
and I want to have a new list `b`
with `(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)`

In python, you could just have `a * 3`

How can this be achieved in Kotlin?

Comment: For simple case you can use `val b = a + a + a`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is creating a list of lists and `flatten`-ing it:

```kotlin
val count = 3
val a = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val b = List(count) { a }.flatten()
println(b) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

From this you can write your own `*` operator:

```kotlin
operator fun <T> Iterable<T>.times(count: Int): List<T> = List(count) { this }.flatten()
```

And use it like in Python:

```kotlin
val a = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val b = a * 3
```

Comment: I edited because there is `flatten()` as a shorthand for `flatMap { it }`

Comment: If you need to use it often, you can also define your own `*` operator for this. I added it to the answer.

Comment: + style points if you make it an `infix operator fun`

Comment: @ArthurKhazbulatov what's the point? The `*` operator is already infix, you wouldn't call this function using its name anyway. You can write `list * 3` no matter whether `times` is declared `infix` or not. See https://pl.kotl.in/ylOWW9KFM

Comment: How do you know I wouldn't? I would, and I do, because in case of repeating a list, `times` can arguably read better than `*`: `listOf(1, 2, 3) times 3`.

Answer (score 4):

You can overload [times operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#arithmetic-operators) in order to use `a * 3`

```
operator fun <T> MutableList<T>.times(increment: Int) {
    val len = this.size
    repeat(increment - 1) {
        this += this.subList(0, len)
    }
}
```

which is simple `a+a+a` like shown here [Plus and minus operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-plus-minus.html)

And now you can use it as `*` operator:

```
val a = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val b = mutableListOf("1", "2", "3", "4")
a * 3
b * 3
print(a)
print(b)

//output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

also you might want to handle negative and zero cases, right now they won't change the List

```
val a = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val b = mutableListOf("1", "2", "3", "4")
a * -1
b * 0
print(a)
print(b)

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```